# Read json key value but ignore object

Tags: scala, dictionary, play-json

I have the below json

```
"atrr": {
     "data": {
          "id": "asfasfsaf",
          "name": "cal",
          "type": "state"
          "ref": [
            "xyz",
            "uhz",
            "arz"
          ]
        }
}
```

I am reading this as below but not getting value k,v

```
def getData: Map[String, String] = (atrr \ "data").asOpt[Map[String, String]].getOrElse(Map[String, String]())
```

without `ref` it works fine.how do I ignore ref[] from json in code that is an object

Comment: What library are you using to parse/represent the JSON?

Comment: @Dylan play.api.libs.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom `Reads[Map[String, String]]`, passed to the `.as` or `.asOpt` method. My approach is to use `Reads.optionNoError[String]` to handle the values inside the main `atrr` object, so that any non-string field which would have caused an error will instead be treated as a `None`.

```scala
// explicitly construct something that'd normally be constructed implicitly
val customReads: Reads[Map[String, Option[String]] = 
  Reads.map(Reads.optionNoError[String])

// pass the custom reads explicitly with parens,
// instead of passing the expect type in square brackets
(atrr \ "data").asOpt(customReads)
```

This results in

```
Some(
  Map(
    id -> Some(asfasfsaf), 
    name -> Some(cal), 
    type -> Some(state), 
    ref -> None
  )
)
```

which you can transform how you see fit, for example by doing

```
.map(_.collect { case (k, Some(v)) => k -> v })
```

Comment: Thanks..but one thing how do map it with  other Map[String,String].Please suggest

Comment: I have updated the question ..pls suggest

Comment: I couldn't figure out what's going wrong from the details you provided, but I recommend you open a new question rather than continuing to edit this one.